# Turn my ui-router into ngRoute code

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

here's my ui-router sample code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jXTA0uU47JAcw7SNb2tj?p=preview

This app is using ui-router, I want to transfer this into ng-route because my project is using ng-route already. I cant find any solution for using both ui-router & ngRoute in one angular config.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

   routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

     $stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })


    // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
    });

});
```

Comment: You can't use both, it's one or the other. There is no quick way to convert from one to the other, you will have to create your ng-route routes manually. Unless you have tons, in which case you can write so fun code to extract and generate new source code :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```